# Is there a code in R that gives me the difference between 2 categories in the same column dependent on other criteria?

Tags: r

Below you find the dp() of my data, it is just a minimized version (5 variables with 32 obs.).

This data represents the **average** of well being (scaled from 1 to 5) by different social classes(3 categories: working class, lower-middle class and upper-middle class) in Austria and Beligum over the years 2007, 2008, 2009 and 2010.

While i was able show how these **mean** of well being have progressed over these 4 years by different social classes. I would like to show the difference between the categories over the 4 years. Let's suppose Working class had a mean of (2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6) in 2007 to 2010 and the upper-middle class had a mean of (1, 1, 1.1, 1.2). How can i create variable that is easily plottable on ggplot that shows me the difference between the two (1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4). And i have to do it for both countries in the same data frame. I know how to do it on Stata but i am shifting to R, so i need some help if it is possible please.

```
dd <- structure(list(class_f = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                     3L, 3L), .Label = c("Working class", "Lower-middle class", "Upper-middle class"
                                     ), class = "factor"), cntry_f = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Cyprus", 
                                                                                                         "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", 
                                                                                                         "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", 
                                                                                                         "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", 
                                                                                                         "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", 
                                                                                                         "United kingdom"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(2007, 
                                                                                                                                                                  2008, 2009, 2010, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
                                                                                                                                                                  2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
                                                                                                                                                                  2010), format.stata = "%9.0g"), health = c(1.7773554167798, 1.88979159307665, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             1.88750969743988, 1.88714499252616, 1.87416331994645, 1.85660377358491, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             1.89224572004028, 1.88572829818538, 1.59277214631996, 1.68942842690946, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             1.71044776119403, 1.67256235827664, 1.79266428935303, 1.82063008130081, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             1.80223285486443, 1.81260184682238, 1.60523665659617, 1.60983263598326, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             1.63365282215122, 1.61392405063291, 1.73519163763066, 1.73280098280098, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             1.71906923950057, 1.72660238230289), cntry_i = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                class_f = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Working class", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Lower-middle class", "Upper-middle class"), class = "factor"), 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                cntry_f = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Austria", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "United kingdom"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5:8, 9:12, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             13:16, 17:20, 21:24), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help in getting you started. I tend to use `ggplot2` for charts and `tidyverse` for data manipulation.

First, it looks like you want to calculate differences between means of the pairs of classes. For this example, I computed the difference between `health` of "Working class" with the other classes using `mutate` (creating a new column, `class_diff_working`). This was done after `group_by`, so it will do this for each country and each year. Then, using `filter`, rows of data pertaining to "Working class" are removed, since we're only interested in the difference with "Working class" as reference.

The second part of the code is plotting using `ggplot`. Here, using `aes` (aesthetic) you define the x-axis, y-axis, and can color `fill` by the `class_f`. `geom_bar` will add a layer of bars, and uses `position_dodge()` if you want to compare lower- and upper-middle classes next to each other. `facet_grid` will allow you to make separate plots by country.

The rest of the plotting code defines the labels, plot title, and legend title. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

dd %>%
  group_by(cntry_f, year) %>%
  mutate(class_diff_working = health[class_f == "Working class"] - health) %>%
  filter(class_f != "Working class") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = class_diff_working, fill = class_f)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
    facet_grid(cols = vars(cntry_f)) +
    xlab("Year") +
    ylab("Difference in Means from Working Class") +
    ggtitle("Difference in Well Being by Country") +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Class"))
```

**Plot**

[image: bar plot of differences in means]